# How to determine eigenvalues for a matrix with one symbolic variable?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, eigenvalue

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of a matrix in which all the elements contain a symbolic variable 'w' in MATLAB. When using the eig function with a small matrix, for example 5x5, Matlab returns the answer in short time but for my case with 75x75 matrix there is no result even in a day.
For example, below are few elements of the matrix Wlbda_M from the first column:

```
             (19532474732762832754894582760668901397*w^2)/2126764793255865396646091296448551321600 - 77109107202987061502201190106698982274469935551/713623846352979940529142984724747568191373312
        (6440060630888147986147319697353091797*w^2)/1329227995784915872903807060280344576000 - 441341856681457924546721557987419671668917039305/2854495385411919762116571938898990272765493248
        (7953990508504513613228552266816516309*w^2)/5316911983139663491615228241121378304000 - 993090640147003256075497986972973808296498643729/5708990770823839524233143877797980545530986496
 - (7271843221507172811594735115331301459*w^2)/10633823966279326983230456482242756608000 - 28245878827613205686092124283481825395002044322201/182687704666362864775460604089535377456991567872
    - (2565513214405907267970563627562325279*w^2)/5316911983139663491615228241121378304000 - 1233745715247789216300571967285405031051699895955/11417981541647679048466287755595961091061972992
    (12880121261776288141689407588821663767*w^2)/2658455991569831745807614120560689152000 - 14122939413806629582719652926085181680332441367949/91343852333181432387730302044767688728495783936
     (5577903399461689618556599053897735153*w^2)/1329227995784915872903807060280344576000 - 22284793286830406982057530040409776590196357698433/91343852333181432387730302044767688728495783936
       (2974250232197768416038223182987456933*w^2)/2658455991569831745807614120560689152000 - 1611348533537140336395461230689378256028220143909/5708990770823839524233143877797980545530986496
  - (9119615798509512940063368481418612157*w^2)/10633823966279326983230456482242756608000 - 11142396643415184739757301830243256383084598479265/45671926166590716193865151022383844364247891968
       - (3080691908882112403687298624070229553*w^2)/5316911983139663491615228241121378304000 - 110335464170364107314736252830024866033040200773/713623846352979940529142984724747568191373312
```

To determine the eigenvalues I used the following command.

```
lbda_V=eig(Wlbda_M);
```

Comment: Have you considered that your numbers are just very, very, very big? Especially having them hand-typed it seems slightly odd. Could you please elaborate on your problem, i.e. why do you need to solve this matrix and where do the numbers come from? Perhaps there's a different solution to your problem.

Comment: It would be good if you describe the reason to why you are using symbolic variables. Why do need to define the symbolic parameter `w`? Symbolic calculation is always very time consuming and create lengthy expressions - you should avoid it at all costs! If you could explain better your problem, maybe a better (numerical) solution can be sought.

Comment: Actually, once the eigenvalues are calculated. The next step I need to again put those values in another equation and solve for the variable w.

Comment: The variables aren't hand typed it is resulting solution of a series of calculations.

Comment: What you are observing is somewhat expected. Solving the eigenvalues has a complexity of O(n^3), increasing n from 5 to 75 increases the complexity by (75/5)^3=3375, but that isn't even the whole picture, that is the factor you would see for a numeric solution. An increased number of steps results in potentially more steps which have to be solved with a higher accuracy to achieve the intended number of significant digits.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the feedback... Is there a possibility to perhaps use parallel computation techniques for eigenvalue calculations? I am not sure about any advance mathematical techniques to make it faster.